# Windows Server 2016: Users dir taking over C: drive due to high load. Can I set a default location for new and current user AppData on another drive?

Tags: windows-server-2016, disk-space-utilization

I'm working with a virtual Windows Server 2016 that's C: drive is filling up due to a high number of Users (over 2,000).  The server acts as a Citrix host, which is leading to AppData dirs averaging 100MB or more.

I'm wondering if there's a way to redirect all current and new Users' AppData (ideally their entire Users dir) to another drive.  I work in an environment where it would be difficult to simply request more space on the C: drive, but getting more space on an E: drive is no issue.

I realize this is likely a good reason to build out another server for the same purpose.  However, I'd like to find a solution that requires as few more servers as possible.  Again, being able to push these large dirs to another server seems like a good way to manage this.

Please let me know if I can explain anything further and I appreciate any ideas that could be suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can't redirect for new users, but you can make a Group Policy to redirect the AppData folder to another folder which can be hosted into your network.

For the GPO, as it' a user policy, please make sure to create a WMI filter, the simpliest one is to create one that target TS server. That  way that redirection will be applied only when theuser log in the TS/Citrix server, not when he log in inside is local workstation.

For example it's there;

[image]

The WMI filter would look that way; you could add the ProductYpe for the OS too

```
ProductType 1 = Desktop OS

ProductType 2 = Server OS – Domain Controller

**ProductType 3 = Server OS – Not a Domain Controller**
```

[image]